# Can't run .NET app on systems without Visual Studio installed

Tags: .net, windows

I have a simple .NET application that I am trying to run on Windows 7.

The application runs on machines with different versions of Visual Studio (2005 & 2013) installed.

It doesn't run on other Windows 7 machines however (one with SP1, and one without).
Initially I got an 0xc000007b error, but that has gone away since installing the .NET runtime.

Now the application still doesn't start but there are no errors, there is also nothing in the Event Viewer at all.

**Things I have tried:**

1. Install VC++ redistributable package
2. Run Dependency walker (nothing special)
3. Check .NET reflector for missing dependencies (everything imported is in the directory, or system libraries)
4. Run Procmon (nothing stood out, but I'm new to the tool and might have missed something)

Comment: Is your application compiled for x86 or x64?

Comment: `I have a simple .NET application` If it's "_simple_" as in "_hello world_ simple" then post the code, build settings and VS version. If it's more than that, try to build a rock-bottom-simple applet and see if that works on the other machines. If it does, compare the code and external references until you find the relevant difference.

Comment: @The_Black_Smurf  target platform is "Any CPU", with "Prefer 32-bit"

Comment: @dxiv Not "Hello world" simple sorry (and I can't post the code as it is my employer's)

Comment: Is this a winform or a WPF application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, and thought I would document it for others.

I added a try catch block on "InitializeComponents", with a message box printing out the exception.

It turns out there was an OCX used in the company that wasn't installed on the target machine, so once I registered the OCX, the application started up.

(The OCX had previously been installed on other development machines for a different project, and simply forgotten).